# catkin_make, invoking CMake error in Raspberry pi 2

Tags: ros, catkin-make, raspberrypi, raspbian, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I just installed ROS indigo on my raspberry pi 2 (with the most recent version of Raspbian).
I followed installration guide at ROS wiki.
(http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi#Create_a_catkin_Workspace)

After all installation steps, except '3.1 Updating the workspace' chapter, I saw that my turtle moved by my arrow keys.

However, when I tried to use 'catkin_make' command at my catkin workspace folder, CMake error occured.
Following is the error message.

```
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation. Try the 'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CmakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)

--Configuring incomplete, errors occured!
Inovking "cmake" failed
```

One of my college succesfully built catkin workspace with 'catkin_make' command, but he don't remember how he done that.

Do I have to use catkin_make_isolated command instead of catkim_make all the time, while I use ROS at Raspberry pi2 with raspbian?
I'm not familiar with Linux, so it would be great thanks to teach me why does this cmake error happen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212996/catkin_make,-invoking-cmake-error-in-raspberry-pi-2/) by [Skunk_works](https://answers.ros.org/users/23067/skunk_works/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Skunk_works](https://answers.ros.org/users/23067/skunk_works/) on 2015-07-07**:
Self simple answering.
'orocos_kdl' and 'python_orocos_kdl' packages are plane cmake packages. Therefore, catkin_make command couldn't build them and gave me error message.

Additional question at here.
Do I need these packages? Where do they come from? Are they necessary packages for ros-comm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can solve this by moving the non catkin packages into a folder on their own and installting them. Then you can use catkin_make for the rest of the ROS stuff

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amadojoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/47187/amadojoao/) on 2019-10-14**:
What is a non catkin package? How can I find them?

**Comment by [dharmendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/53048/dharmendra/) on 2020-04-26**:
how can i find non-catkin packages?